# Convert a concrete model in an abstract one

Tags: pyomo

I am just starting with Pyomo and I have a big problem. 
I want to run an Abstract Model without using the terminal. I can do it with a concrete model but I have serious problems to do it in with the abstract one.

I just want to use F5 and run the code.

This ismy program:

```
import pyomo
from pyomo.environ import *
#
# Model
#
model = AbstractModel()



#Set: Indices
model.Unit = Set()
model.Block = Set()
model.DemBlock = Set()
#Parameters
model.EnergyBid = Param(model.Unit, model.Block)
model.PriceBid = Param(model.Unit, model.Block)
model.EnergyDem = Param(model.DemBlock)
model.PriceDem = Param(model.DemBlock)
model.Pmin = Param(model.Unit)
model.Pmax = Param(model.Unit)
#Variables definition
model.PD = Var(model.DemBlock, within=NonNegativeReals)
model.PG = Var(model.Unit,model.Block, within=NonNegativeReals)
#Binary variable
model.U = Var(model.Unit, within = Binary)
#Objective
def SocialWellfare(model):
    SocialWellfare = sum([model.PriceDem[i]*model.PD[i] for i in model.DemBlock]) - sum([model.PriceBid[j,k]*model.PG[j,k] for j in model.Unit for k in model.Block ])
    return SocialWellfare
model.SocialWellfare = Objective(rule=SocialWellfare, sense=maximize)
#Constraints
#Max and min Power generated
def PDmax_constraint(model,p):
    return ((model.PD[p] - model.EnergyDem[p])) <= 0
model.PDmax = Constraint(model.DemBlock, rule=PDmax_constraint)
def PGmax_constraint(model,n,m):
    return ((model.PG[n,m] - model.EnergyBid[n,m])) <= 0
model.PGmax = Constraint(model.Unit, model.Block,rule = PGmax_constraint)
def Power_constraintDW(model,i):
    return ((sum(model.PG[i,k] for k in model.Block))-(model.Pmin[i] * model.U[i]) ) >= 0
model.LimDemandDw = Constraint(model.Unit, rule=Power_constraintDW)
def Power_constraintUP(model,i):
    return ((sum(model.PG[i,k] for k in model.Block) - (model.Pmax[i])*model.U[i])) <= 0
model.LimDemandaUp = Constraint(model.Unit, rule=Power_constraintUP)
def PowerBalance_constraint(model):
    return (sum(model.PD[i] for i in model.DemBlock) - sum(model.PG[j,k] for j in model.Unit for k in model.Block)) == 0
model.PowBalance = Constraint(rule = PowerBalance_constraint)



model.pprint()
instance = model.create('datos_transporte.dat')

## Create the ipopt solver plugin using the ASL interface
solver = 'ipopt'
solver_io = 'nl'
opt = SolverFactory(solver,solver_io=solver_io)

results = opt.solve(instance)
results.write()
```

Any help with the last part??

Thanks anyway,

Comment: At first glance, your model looks syntactically fine.  There are a few corrections for the current Pyomo version (you don't need the `import pyomo` line, and in current Pyomo versions we recommend creating the instance with `model.create_instance('datos_transporte.dat')`), but I ran your model with current Pyomo and didn't get any errors (except for not having your .dat file). What specific error/problem are you running into?  What version of Pyomo are you using?  What data file are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is actually working.  Starting in Pyomo 4.1, the solution returned from the solver is stored directly into the instance that was solved, and is *not* returned in the solver results object.  This change was made because generating the representation of the solution in the results object was rather expensive and was not easily parsed by people.  Working with the model instance directly is more natural.

It is unfortunate that the results object reports the `number of solutions: 0`, although this is technically correct: the results object holds no solutions ... but the Solver section should indicate that a solution was returned and stored into the model instance.

If you want to see the result returned by the solver, you can print out the current status of the model using:

```
instance.display()
```

after the call to `solve()`.  That will report the current `Var` values that were returned from the solver.  You will want to pay attention to the `stale` column:

- `False` indicates the value is not "stale" ... that is, it was either set by the user (before the call to `solve()`), or it was returned from the solver (after the call to `solve()`).
- `True` indicates the solver did not return a value for that variable.  This is usually because the variable was not referenced by the objective or any enabled constraints, so Pyomo never sent the variable to the solver.

[Note: `display()` serves a slightly different role than `pprint()`: `pprint()` outputs the model *structure*, whereas `display()` outputs the model *state*.  So, for example, where `pprint()` will output the constraint expressions, `display()` will output the numerical value of the expression (using the current variable/param values).]

---

**Edit**ed to expand the discussion of `display()` & `pprint()`